# Cygwin sshd intermittently getting 'ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer' or not finding binaries

Tags: ssh, cygwin

When I `ssh` to the windows box, on occasion programs on the path are not found, or I get `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`, typically when more than 10 simultaneous connections happen (the Windows box is a build server).  This happens reliably if I force more than 15 simultaneous connections. The issue happens reliably independent of where I connect from

Here's what I see when I force several simultaneous connections:

```
$ for i in `seq 1 20`; do ssh -x bdedev-pw-530 'which /usr/bin/env'  2>&1 |tee log.$i || echo FAILED& done; wait 2> /dev/null
[1] 21492
[2] 21494
[3] 21496
[4] 21500
[5] 21506
[6] 21514
[7] 21519
[8] 21522
[9] 21525
[10] 21527
[11] 21532
[12] 21535
[13] 21539
[14] 21548
[15] 21552
[16] 21557
[17] 21561
[18] 21565
[19] 21572
[20] 21576
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
/usr/bin/env
```

As you can see, most of the time, `/usr/bin/env` is found, but on occasion, it is not.  Sometimes, that failure is associated with an `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` error, but not in all cases.

Any suggestions?  Anything I could do to get more debugging info to help track this down?

I'm running cygwin's sshd (installed via `ssh-host-config`) on a Windows Server 2019 host, running cygwin DLL version: 3.3.4, and the latest ssh package (as of a few weeks ago: `OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021`).

The server has 28 physical cores (56 logical), and over 512GB of ram, so I suspect this isn't a memory or CPU issue.

I've got neither binmode nor ntsec set for the `CYGWIN` variable.

Comment: `sshd` needs to find the shell. The shell needs to find `which`. `which` needs to find `/usr/bin/env`. You assumed "sshd intermittently not finding …", but it's possible it's something else. In the first place the local `ssh` may be unable to connect for some reason. A reasonable thing to do is to make your commands loud: no `-q` for `ssh`, `ssh -v` if needed, no `2>/dev/null` (in general, it seems harmless where you used it), etc.

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski - edited with more info after removing the -q.  However, in production, the failure mode isn't always ```ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer```, as I can see the programs running on the server but not finding binaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenSSH server has some configuration options to control what it does when it receives a large number of client connections at the same time:

> [**MaxStartups**](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#MaxStartups)
> Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated connections to the SSH daemon. Additional connections will be dropped until authentication succeeds or the LoginGraceTime expires for a connection. The default is 10:30:100.
>
> Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the three colon separated values start:rate:full (e.g. "10:30:60"). sshd(8) will refuse connection attempts with a probability of rate/100 (30%) if there are currently start (10) unauthenticated connections. The probability increases linearly and all connection attempts are refused if the number of unauthenticated connections reaches full (60).

> [**PerSourceMaxStartups**](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PerSourceMaxStartups)
> Specifies the number of unauthenticated connections allowed from a given source address, or “none” if there is no limit. This limit is applied in addition to MaxStartups, whichever is lower. The default is none.

You're opening over a dozen connections to the server at more or less the same time. You may be running into the "MaxSessions" limit. The default behavior will start dropping connections if it has accepted 10 or more connections that haven't finished authenticating yet.

You would change this limit this by editing the [OpenSSH server configuration file](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config), usually named "sshd_config", on the remote server. Add a value for MaxSessions to the file, or edit the entry if it's already there, to permit more than 10 connections at a time. Be sure to restart `sshd` after editing the configuration file.

Alternately, you could be running into the "PerSourceMaxStartups" limit. But that feature is disabled by default, so it would only be in effect if it's set to a value in your server's sshd_config file.

If you don't want to reconfigure the server, you could add a short delay between ssh invocations to avoid having so many connect the remote server at essentially the same time:

```
for i in `seq 1 20`
do
    ssh -x bdedev-pw-530 'which /usr/bin/env'  2>&1 |tee log.$i || echo FAILED&
    sleep 1    ### Sleep a bit between invocations
done
wait 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solved the ssh_exchange_identification issue!  I'll open another question if I can find a way to reproduce the other problem I occasionally see, where binaries in the PATH aren't found intermittently in ssh connections.